# MVVM Cross WP8 unviersal Entry Point not found

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, mvvmcross

I try to set up an project with MVVM Cross in Windows Phone 8.1 Universal App. I used this tutorial: https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/wiki/Tip-Calc-A-Universal-Windows-App-UI-Project

Now I always get the following exception:
Program does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable for an entry point [Project].WindowsPhone

In the App Project is the entry point defined as App.cs In this class I only changed this:

```
            var setup = new Setup(rootFrame);
            setup.Initialize();

            var start = Mvx.Resolve<IMvxAppStart>();
            start.Start();
```

And this setup class:

```
public class Setup : MvxWindowsSetup
{
    public Setup(Frame rootFrame) : base(rootFrame)
    {
    }

    protected override IMvxApplication CreateApp()
    {
        return new Core.App();
    }
}
```

Does anyone have an idea what's the reason for that? o.O

Thanks
NPadrutt

EDIT: I could solve it with creating a new project and add the hot tuna starter package. From there I added the Android and ios files from the other project one by one again.

Comment: Have you looked through other questions with similar errors - http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=+Program+does+not+contain+a+static+%27Main%27+method+suitable+for+an+entry+point+

Comment: yeah, but this didn't work out for me.. In the end I just recreated the project from scratch and added the other files again.

Answer (score 2):

The solution is to set the "Build Action" of your App.xaml file to "ApplicationDefinition".

If you did what I did, you at some point added an App.xaml file from scratch and this sets the build definition incorrectly.

[image]